# Unified Linux server utilization monitoring

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring

I use a whole bunch of tools to monitor server load (Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP) of different types - top, iostat and netstat, as well as my own in-script measurements. I collect and summarize the data using scripts and spreadsheets, to get an overall picture of what's keeping my server busy.

Is there a simple tool/daemon I can install under Linux which will sit quietly in the background, collect all this information at appropriate intervals, and then provide simple daily/weekly/monthly summaries for me to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone mentioned ***sar*** (system activity reporter) and I have to second that recommendation!

It sounds like you've done a boatload of work on your own with various tools.  However, you might have found that most of the aggregate system data you're interested in has been collected by *sadc* (system activity data collector) cron jobs for as long as you've had the *sysstat* package installed on your systems.
'
Oddly enough these don't run as daemons.

The *sadc* scripts (named *sa1* and sa2) collect information from various kernel counters ... some of them are the same that are queried by *vmstat* and others are pulled from the same sources that *ifconfig* uses to report on the amount of data transmitted and received on each interface, and so on.  By default *sa1* runs every 10 minutes.

The *sar* command can then be used to pull various subsets of this information from the collected data.  To become familiar with all available tables run *sar -A* and redirect the output to some convenient file.  Then open the file in your favorite editor, in one window, and bring up the *sar* man page in another.  Now simply walk through the entire file, searching the man page for the various column heading identifiers.

I also like to use *sar **-A*** as an early step for troubleshooting unexplained performance and stability.  (Often by the time such issues have been escalated to me the system has already been rebooted or the problem is intermittent).  This data is often the best available since the user (including most of the junior and intermediate sysadmins I've worked with) don't know what sort of data to collect before rebooting.

The trick to using this data for post-mortem troubleshooting is to scan all those columns of numbers looking for the spikes.  (Yes, if you're good with tools like GNUplot you could generate a bunch of graphs from them; but honestly you can often spot the spikes just as well just scanning along the raw numbers).  Look at a few similar systems which are not exhibiting the issues, or look at the data on this system during intervals when the things seem to be fine.  Once you spot the "spikes" (network traffic, paging activity, disk I/O) try to correlate them (I usually just make a copy of the data and delete all the "nominal" data to leave me with just the stuff that's probably probative).  The first correlation to look for is in the timing of different resource spikes ... did the run queue suddenly spike just before paging climbed out of control?  ... was there a huge increase in received network traffic just before the disk I/O numbers went through the roof?  Then you correlate that to the output from the *last* command (who was logged in around then) ... and if you've enabled process accounting then you can look at the *lastcomm* command.  And, naturally, you can also look at */var/log/** to focus on the same time interval (and scanning backwards from there, of course).

You'd be amazed at how much you can figure out from this exercise.

"Tom account logged in, a few minutes later that were gradually increasing data flows over eth0 and to the sdb3 disk; perhaps he was copying in a data set, probably from the Netapps over on Lan B ... then we see a huge spike in memory page allocations, but process creation remained nominal until this paging started; that's when the interrupts and run queue went through the room, and brought the system into OOM thrashing.  Tom, you ignoramus!  You have a memory leak in foobar.pl!" :)

However, for your purposes you can use *sar -A* just as a starting point.  You find the bits that you need and then you call *sar* with various arguments to capture each table you want to parse, filter, and graph separately.  There are options to render the output in a more machine friendly format, as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are several tools that let you automatically collect performance metrics for your servers, like for example [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) and [Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/).

Most of the monitoring solutions provide a web-based frontend from which you can easily visualize performance data corresponding to a specific time period. Besides, as they usually store the collected information on a database, you can also take advantage of that in case you need to perform further analysis.

Answer (score 2):

`sar` is the system activity reporting command.  It can provide realtime data (similar to vmstat), and also saves data in the background for later reporting.

Debian has a few different versions in their repository, look at the `atsar` and `sysstat` packages.

You may also find process accounting interesting.  When any process finishes, it's usage information is written to a file from which reports can be made.  Look at the `acct` package.

Comment: Sar gooooooood.

Answer (score 2):

You could use :

1.[**SeaLion**](http://sealion.com).Its a light weight tool. Since you prefered SAR for usage, this would be further attractive as to me it seemed like an extension of SAR; with all outputs on a timeline(helps debug w.r.t. time) also supporting all possible shell commands that one can think of. Top, iostat, netstat, uptime,etc are default commands provided and it also allows you to add your own commands and configure the interval at which to collect the outputs. However it does not provide alerts yet.

2.[**New Relic**](http://newrelic.com/) : It tops the list of server monitoring tools and provides reports in the form of graphs and also provides alerts. It is a bit heavy and tough to set up.

These are the only two I have used and can vouch for.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently discovered [Glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances) and from ssh is pretty good, more than top and htop. This for a single machine.

For monitoring all your servers (virtual or physical) yes [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) is pretty good, and recently [Monitis](http://www.monitis.com/) as a backup choice. Also [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) paid account is a complete set of utility.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/). You can define templates for type of hardware or kinds of usage. You can send reports, alerts, by differents medias like mail, jabber or SMS (if you have a GSM or CDMA modem). Datas are collected by SNMP or by its own zabbix-agent.

Comment: zabbix is nice; you can also insert your measurements directly in its database for later graphing.

Answer (score 0):

you try following link it has lot of thing for monitoring..

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html